# Making the scroll animation not stopping but smooth

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, smoothing

Do you guys have any idea to get this (http://hvlmnns.de/middle/) smoother?
on my system it stucks a bit.

Would also be nice to have this kinda ios afterscroll effect.

here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var wx=$(window).width(),wy=$(window).height(),dx=$(document).width(),dy=$(document).height();
$('html,body').width(dx).height(dy).stop().animate({scrollTop:(dy-wy)/2,scrollLeft:((dx-wx)/2)},0);
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var x=(dx-wx)*((e.pageX-$(window).scrollLeft())/wx);
    var y=(dy-wy)*((e.pageY-$(window).scrollTop())/wy);
    $('body').scrollLeft(x).scrollTop(y);

});
});
```

im no sure about this animate and dequeue() stuff but i think it will be the solution in the end but how i said have no clue to smoothen a scroll animation without being stopped all the time.

Comment: Try to code your own animation with requestAnimationFrame. Change variables on mousemove, use them in requestAnimationFrame loop.

Comment: funny :) it doesent depends on the cpu it's stucking because i move pixels with decimal places

Comment: I like your question +1

Comment: @StefanHövelmanns then use `Math.round(dx)` instead of just `dx` or something, to have whole integers.

Comment: It runs smooth on my machine. Any particular browser to use?

Comment: i'do use ff. Anyhow i would like to do this with an animation so i can mess around with easings and stuff. but when i do use them i have the stop() problem that i always have. im getting into equestAnimationFrame now

Comment: hm not getting into it and actually it just smooths the 'animation' but i dont have any in there so not very usefull. i would like to have an animation fired wich is always animating the scroll position smoothly !towards! my two vars

Answer (score 0):

kinda figured it out
http://hvlmnns.de/middle/

not the smoothest thing and not the best but this has to do the job

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').css({
        position: 'relative',
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    })
    var wx = $(window).width(),
        wy = $(window).height(),
        dx = $(document).width(),
        dy = $(document).height();
    $('body').width(dx).height(dy).scrollTop((dy - wy) / 2).scrollLeft((dx - wx) / 2);
    var x = 0,
        y = 0;
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        x = (dx - wx) * ((e.pageX - $(window).scrollLeft()) / wx);
        y = (dy - wy) * ((e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop()) / wy);
    });
    var obj = $('body');
    var xp = 0,
        yp = 0;
    $('body').scrollTop((dy - wy) / 2).scrollLeft((dx - wx) / 2);
    var loop = setInterval(function () {
        xp += (x - xp) / 60;
            yp += (y - yp) / 60;
        obj.scrollTop(yp).scrollLeft(xp);
    }, 1);
});
```